# Normal distribution of input data

Tags: pandas, neural-network, normalization, distribution, recurrent-neural-network

Should I normalize input data to normal distribution before fit it into RNN? If yes, why? At the moment almost all the columns are right shifted, so it's not a normal distribution at all.

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to transform the inputs to a normal distribution, but you might want to preprocess them so that the majority of each of their values is between 0 and 1. Otherwise, when using sigmoid functions for internal nodes, you may cause [saturation](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2017/07/06/neural-network-saturation/). If your inputs are each *U(0, 1000)*, for example, then there's no need to transform to normal distributions, but rather to just scale by 0.001.

Comment: Ami Tavory, Thank you!

Comment: @DavidGoldman You're welcome.